# I get error in console when use "v-if" directive. Infinite loop

Tags: vue.js, compiler-errors, vuejs2, syntax-error, warnings

After when I use v-if, I get a [Vue warn] in my console, no idea how to solve this problem.
[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

```
<template>
  <div class="example-component">
      <div class="spinner-box" v-if="loadComplete = !loadComplete">
        <div class="spinner-inner">
          <i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ExampleComponent',
  data () {
    return {
      loadComplete: false
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Note: I just need to make preloader before I get data from firebase, maybe have other solutions and don't need to use v-if or whatever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
v-if="loadComplete = !loadComplete"
```

To

```
v-if="!loadComplete"
```

Example

https://2ozkjp4vyp.codesandbox.io/

[image: Edit Vue Template]

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <img width=200 src="./assets/logo.png">
        <div class="loader" v-if="!loadComplete"></div>
        <div v-else>
            <p>asynchronous data from firebase</p>
            <button @click="loadDataFromFirebase">Reload</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    name: 'app',
        data: () => ({
            loadComplete: false
        }),
        mounted () {
            this.loadDataFromFirebase()
        },
        methods: {
            loadDataFromFirebase () {
                this.loadComplete = false
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.loadComplete = true
                }, 1000)
            }
        }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but not working here. I want to explain what I want to do, maybe have some other way to solve this. 
I want to make some preloader(spinner) in my portfolio before I get data from my firebase, and I want to make something like I use to do on jQuery or JS.
For example, i provide function below:
$(window).on('load', function () {
    var body = $('body');
    body.removeClass('loaded');
});
I don't know maybe I use wrong things to do that. Any thoughts?

Comment: I add an example. check it out and hope it helps

Comment: Wow, I'm tried the same, but without setTimeout, thank you a lot for helping me, and figuring it out. It's a very useful example, I'm betting not only for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify where the infinite update loop came.

The `v-if="loadComplete = !loadComplete"` is an assignment, where you are assigning the value `!loadComplete` to `loadComplete`. Whenever you assign a variable in Vue it will trigger a new render, and on the next render it is executing the same assignment again... and this result in an infinite loop.

@PaulTsai gave a great example using the correct way `v-if="!loadComplete"`

Comment: Thank you for a feedback, I appreciate that. Shame I can't vote because my reputation is less than 15.

Comment: don't worry, keep going :)